# Octopus Server keeps crashing after upgrade to 2.4.8 version

Tags: upgrade, octopus-deploy

I have upgraded the Octopus server from version 2.0 to 2.4 recently. It manages to install the server but keeps crashing with the following error:-

```
System.Exception: The HTTP server could not start because namespace reservations have not been made. Ensure that the current user has access to listen on these prefixes by running the following command(s):
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8081/octopus/ user=test\SYSTEM
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8081/octopus/ user=test\SYSTEM
```

Tried un-installing and installing again.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge I can say to use the following commands as an example:

```
netsh http add urlacl url = http:// + : 8080 / user=\Everyone
```

You should adjust the ports and/or path as necessary for your situation:

```
netsh http add urlacl url = http:// + : 8080/MyConsoleAppHostedService user=DOMAIN\user

netsh http add urlacl url=http:// + : 8091/MyWindowsServiceHostedService user=\SYSTEM
```

to delete an urlacl do:

```
delete urlacl url = https:// * : 8172/
```